# Get Postgresql Data Output in Java

Tags: java, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.5

I have a function in Postgresql that in Data Output shows true or false.
Apparently since java executes the function, but how do I obtain the Data Output in Java?

```
sql = "{call read_table_transferencia('msb_personas')}";
System.out.println(sql);
st2 = this.getCn().prepareCall(sql);
wm =st2.execute();
System.out.println(wm.booleanValue());
```

The value in wm is always true, I need the value that the postgresql emits (true or false).

Comment: `st2.execute()` will indeed return `true` if you have resultants `ResultSet`s. Did you verify that, for some scenarios, you wouldn't return always `true` in PostgreSQL itself?

Comment: Yes, the function seems to perform updates, when it concludes satisfactorily it returns true, and when it has some problem it returns false